# How to use aria-expanded="true" to change a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use `aria-expanded="true"` to change a css property like an active class :

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> 
       <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I want the `<a>` to `background-color: #42DCA3` but only when `aria-expanded="true"`.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Why javascript when you can use just css?

```css
a[aria-expanded="true"]{
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
```

```html
<li class="active">
   <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> 
       <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
   <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> 
       <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: 5 years later and still helping to save lines of code.

Comment: What do you do to change the background of the li container?

Comment: @Dgloria It was impossible when I created the answer, but now you can use the new :has() selector.
li:has(a[aria-expanded="true"]){background-color: #42DCA3;}

Only working in Safari right now. If you want it now, you can either add a class to the LI or add ::after and ::before pseudo elements to the A that mock the desired result.

Comment: :has() is now available in Chrome 105

Answer (score 17):

```css
li a[aria-expanded="true"] span{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="active">
    <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

```css
li a[aria-expanded="true"]{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<li class="active">
    <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="network-name">Google+</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `querySelector()` with attribute selector `'[attribute="value"]'`, then affect css rule using `.style`, as you can see in the example below:

```js
document.querySelector('a[aria-expanded="true"]').style.backgroundColor = "#42DCA3";
```

```html
<ul><li class="active">
  <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="network-name">Google+ with aria expanded true</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="network-name">Google+ with aria expanded false</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery solution :**

If you want to use a jQuery solution you could simply use `css()` method :

```
$('a[aria-expanded="true"]').css('background-color','#42DCA3');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you were open to using JQuery, you could modify the background color for any link that has the property `aria-expanded` set to true by doing the following...

```
$("a[aria-expanded='true']").css("background-color", "#42DCA3");
```

Depending on how specific you want to be regarding which links this applies to, you may have to slightly modify your selector.

Comment: yep thats fine, i am using no other aria-expanded. where would i put this piece of code? just in the head. Thanks

Comment: or actually how do i use this at all, never used jquery before